# How can I get module name automatically from __init__.py or conftest.py?

Tags: python, pytest

I am running multiple tests in a tests package, and I want to print each module name in the package, without duplicating code.
So, I wanted to insert some code to `__init__.py` or `conftest.py` that will give me the executing module name.
Let's say my test modules are called: checker1, checker2, etc...

My directory structure is like this:

```
tests_dir/
├── __init__.py
├── conftest.py
├── checker1
├── checker2
└── checker3
```

So, inside `__init__.py` I tried inserting:

```
def module_name():
    return os.path.splitext(__file__)[0]
```

But it still gives me `__init__.py` from each file when I call it.

I also tried using a fixture inside conftest.py, like:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def module_name(request):
    return request.node.name
```

But it seems as if I still need to define a function inside each module to get `module_name` as a parameter.

What is the best method of getting this to work?

## Edit:

In the end, what I did is explained here:

#### conftest.py

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='module', autouse=True)
def module_name(request):
    return request.node.name
```

example for a test file with a test function. The same needs to be added to each file and every function:

#### checker1.py

```
from conftest import *

def test_columns(expected_res, actual_res, module_name):
    expected_cols = expected_res.columns
    actual_cols = actual_res.columns

    val = expected_cols.difference(actual_cols)  # verify all expected cols are in actual_cols
    if not val.empty:
        log.error('[{}]: Expected columns are missing: {}'.format(module_name, val.values))
    assert val.empty
```

Notice the `module_name` fixture I added to the function's parameters.

- **expected_res** and **actual_res** are pandas Dataframes from excel file.
- **log** is a `Logger` object from `logging` package

Answer (score 0):

In each module (checker1, checker2, checker3, conftest.py), in the main function, execute

```
print(__name__)
```

When the `__init__.py` file imports those packages, it should print the module name along with it.

Based on your comment, you can perhaps modify the behaviour in the `__init__.py` file for local imports.

`__init.py__`

```
import sys, os
sys.path.append(os.path.split(__file__)[0])

def my_import(module):
    print("Module name is {}".format(module))
    exec("import {}".format(module))
```

`testerfn.py`

```
print(__name__)
print("Test")
```

Directory structure

```
tests_dir/
├── __init__.py
└── testerfn.py
```

Command to test

```
import tests_dir
tests_dir.my_import("testerfn")
```

Comment: This was the obvious solution, but I wanted to refrain from reusing the same code in each file. Imagine this was not a one-liner, but a function with 20 lines or more...

Comment: Please check if this helps, I have modified the answer

Comment: I upvoted the comment for a good answer, however it does not help me since your "command to test" section is assuming there is another script or environment to run commands from, while there are not. So this code needs to be inside ```testerfn.py``` file itself, where all the other test functions reside. That brings me back to the same issue where each file needs to register itself or send a request to ```__init__.py```.